# AngularJS: radio buttons aren't checked by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm coding some radio buttons in angular, but I cannot make one of the radios appears marked as default.
This is my code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    //And this is the JavaSctipt:

    $scope.locationLookup = 1;
    $scope.updateDropdownValuesBreedingLocation = function() { // Change state for breeding
      // location radio
      $scope.dropdownValues = ($scope.localData.useFavorites) ? $scope.variableDefinition.possibleValuesFavorite : $scope.variableDefinition.possibleValues;
      $scope.locationLookup = 1;
    };

    $scope.updateDropdownValuesAllLocation = function() { // Change state for all locations radio
      $scope.dropdownValues = ($scope.localData.useFavorites) ? $scope.variableDefinition.allFavoriteValues : $scope.variableDefinition.allValues;
      $scope.locationLookup = 2;
    };

<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!-- show-setting-form-element-new.html  -->
    <div ng-switch="widgetType">
    <div ng-switch-when="DROPDOWN">
        <input type="hidden" ui-select2="dropdownOptions" class="form-control select2" ng-model="valuecontainer[targetkey]" value-as-object="false" ng-change="changefunction()" ng-disabled="blockInput"/>
        <div ng-if="isLocation">
            <div class="possibleValuesDiv">
                <input type="radio" ng-disabled="blockInput"
                 ng-model="locationLookup" value=1 ng-change="updateDropdownValuesBreedingLocation()"> &nbsp;
                <span th:text="#{show.breeding.location}">Breeding locations</span> &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" ng-disabled="blockInput" 
                ng-model="locationLookup" value=2 ng-change="updateDropdownValuesAllLocation()"> &nbsp;
                <span th:text="#{show.all.location}">All locations types</span>
            </div>
            <div class="possibleValuesDiv">            
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="localData.useFavorites" ng-checked="true" ng-change="updateDropdownValuesFavorites()"> &nbsp;
                <span th:text="#{show.favorite.location}">Show only favorite locations </span> &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="isBreedingMethod" class="possibleValuesDiv">
            <!--TODO : handle rendering of breeding method dropdowns for completeness-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="NTEXT">
        <input type="text" ng-disabled="blockInput" valid-decimal="" class="form-control numeric-input" ng-model="valuecontainer[targetkey]" ng-change="changefunction()"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="SLIDER">
        <input type="text" ng-disabled="blockInput" valid-decimal="" class="form-control numeric-input" ng-model="valuecontainer[targetkey]" ng-change="changefunction()"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="CTEXT">
        <input type="text" ng-disabled="blockInput" class="form-control character-input" ng-model="valuecontainer[targetkey]" ng-change="changefunction()"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="TEXTAREA">
        <textarea ng-disabled="blockInput" class="form-control character-input" rows="3" ng-model="valuecontainer[targetkey]" ng-change="changefunction()"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="DATE">
        <input type="text" ng-disabled="blockInput" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" class="form-control date-input" ng-model="valuecontainer[targetkey]" jq-datepicker="true" with-image="true" image-src="/Fieldbook/static/img/calendar.png" ng-change="changefunction()"/>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

And the container is this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    <section-container th:attr="heading=#{trial.managesettings.trial.environment.specify.level}">
        <div name="content">

            <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-instance="nested.dtInstance"
                   class="table table-curved table-condensed fbk-table-with-check fbk-datatable-environments" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-sortable="false" class="fbk-delete-link"></th>
                    <th data-sortable="false" th:text="#{trial.managesettings.trial.environment.label}">Environment</th>
                    <th data-sortable="false" ng-repeat="key in settings.managementDetails.keys()"
                        ng-hide="settings.managementDetails.val(key).hidden">
                        {{settings.managementDetails.val(key).variable.name}}</th>
                    <th data-sortable="false" ng-repeat="key in settings.trialConditionDetails.keys()">
                        {{settings.trialConditionDetails.val(key).variable.name}}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="environment in data.environments" ng-class="{even : $even, odd : $odd}">
                    <td class="fbk-delete-link fbk-table-delete-link">
                        <span ng-click="deleteEnvironment($index)" ng-show="data.noOfEnvironments > 1"
                              class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign fbk-delete-sign">&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{environment.managementDetailValues[TRIAL_INSTANCE_NO_INDEX]}}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="key in settings.managementDetails.keys()"
                        ng-hide="settings.managementDetails.val(key).hidden">
                        <show-setting-form-element-new ng-if="isLocation" settings="settings.managementDetails" targetkey="{{key}}"
                                                   valuecontainer="environment.managementDetailValues"
                                                       changefunction="onLocationChange({key: environment.managementDetailValues[key]})"></show-setting-form-element-new>
                        <show-setting-form-element-new ng-if="!isLocation" settings="settings.managementDetails" targetkey="{{key}}"
                                                       valuecontainer="environment.managementDetailValues"></show-setting-form-element-new></td>
                    <td ng-repeat="key in settings.trialConditionDetails.keys()">
                        <show-setting-form-element settings="settings.trialConditionDetails" targetkey="{{key}}"
                                                   valuecontainer="environment.trialDetailValues"></show-setting-form-element></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section-container>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Can you help me?
The most interesting is that if I put these radios outside the table, it works fine! But not inside it.

Comment: This code seems to be working fine. Can we get more of the full picture and a minimal replicable example of the issue you are facing?

Comment: Code shown should work however if you have child scopes involved it is imperative to use an object in `ng-model`. Don't break the golden rule of *"always have a dot in ng-model"*

Comment: @charlietfl or switch to "controller as" syntax. I am astounded how many people do not know about/use "controller as" - https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: I guess the problem is that this code is into a table tag. I also use this code besides the table,and it works fine.